# Why is the hydrolysis constant of a salt of Weak Acid and a Weak Base so?

Tags: equilibrium, hydrolysis

I read that the hydrolysis constant for a salt of a weak acid and a weak base is

Kh=Kw/(Ka*Kb)

Now I recall reading in the autoionization of water that Kw=Ka*Kb.

So, is there any relation between the two here? Can we write KH=kW/kW=1, does that even make any sense?
Or are they completely unrelated and I'm just randomly relating stuff?

Thank you.

Comment: In the 1st formula, Ka and Kb are unrelated, while in the 2nd one they belong to the conjugate acid/base pair.

Comment: @Poutnik Yes! That clears it since I know the derivations. Couldn't thank you more!